# Different behavior of ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource() in servlet container and test environment

Tags: java, servlets, junit, jvm, classloader

I have a web application my requirement is to read some files and process it and persist the file content in database when the application starts.

```
class MyUtil{
/**
*Read the files
*/
 public static void readFiles(){ 

  File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("MyFile").toURI()); //NullPointerException
  // ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("MyFile") is giving null in servlet.init() method.
  if (file.isDirectory()) {
        //Read all the files and persist.
   }
 }
}
```

`MyFile` **folder/dir** is available in class path. When `MyUtil.readFiles()` is called in JUnit test case it works fine. But when It's called in `servelet.init()` method `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("MyFile")` gives the null.

Comment: try using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource` instead. (not static `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`)

Comment: Anyway, why not just use `classpath:/path/to/file` if the folder exist in classpath?

Comment: Thanks you! First suggestion worked. Put it as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)` as an alternative to `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(...)`

The alternative works because in webserver there are more than one class loader, and you can't be sure whichone loaded your class. I guess `ClassLoader` class loaded before anything with default java class loader, and then `MyUtil` class loaded with different class loader with the webserver hence it resulted in different classpath.