# I can't read .properties when I run tomcat with idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, java-web-start

I'm learning JavaWeb and deploying local tomcat9 in idea. An exception occurred when I tried to connect to the database by reading the properties file. It should be that my properties file was not found.

I tried to change the file path but it didn't work. What should I do?

This is my method to connect to the database and message

```
public class JDBCUtil {
    private static DataSource druidSource;
    static {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("production/begin/druid.properties");
        try {
            props.load(is);
            druidSource = DruidDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return druidSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:407)
    at DAO.util.JDBCUtil.<clinit>(JDBCUtil.java:24)
    at servlets.AddServlet.doPost(AddServlet.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

This is my [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3735a.jpg)

Operating environment:MacOS12, idea2021.3.3, tomcat9.0.62, Java16.0.1

Comment: What other filepaths did you try? It's good to mention this. Have you tried just `druid.properties`?

Comment: I also used src/druid.properties and absolute path, none of them work.I use the System.getProperty ("user.dir") method in the static code block, it show that path is /Users/{UserName}/Library/tomcat/bin

Comment: If `druid.properties` is in the same package as `JDBCUtil `, u can try with just `druid.properties`, or maybe `/druid.properties`

Comment: thx, I copy `druid.properties` to same package as `JDBCUtil` and tried the two paths you mentioned, but it still doesn't work.@rehnoj

Comment: Okey, maybe this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869884/different-behavior-of-classloader-getsystemclassloader-getresource-in-servle

Comment: Thanks you! This is right, it is working now!@rehnoj

Comment: Good to hear (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved.Thank for [rehnoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6040762/rehnoj)'s help.

The answer in [Different behavior of ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource() in servlet container and test environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869884/different-behavior-of-classloader-getsystemclassloader-getresource-in-servle).

The correct code

```
public class JDBCUtil {
    private static DataSource druidSource;
    static {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is = JDBCUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("druid.properties");
        try {
            props.load(is);
            druidSource = DruidDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return druidSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```